# Umbraco automatic update

Tags: umbraco

I need some help with umbraco. 
Let's say that I have an umbraco grid with a custom editor, just like the one in this tutorial: https://our.umbraco.com/documentation/Getting-Started/Backoffice/Property-Editors/Built-in-Property-Editors/Grid-Layout/build-your-own-editor

Ok, so I wrote this editor to build a gallery of items with image/title, I get the item list from an api call made by an angular service and this works fine when I publish the page by hand. What I want is to automatically update this gallery with new items where available, so my idea was to make a timed ajax call, let's say every hour, to update the items. But sadly this doesn't work, I suppose that the call is made but the list isn't updated.

Any suggestion? Thanks

Comment: If the call is getting what you need don't you need to write code to 'publish' the page once the list is updated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to handle this differently. Right now it sounds like what you have is an implementation that works when you are browsing to this node in the backoffice using your browser and the browser makes the API calls through Angular. This all happens in your UI and when you manually hit save/publish - the data in the UI gets saved. Keep in mind that this is basically your browser doing the "work" - and this (and all other Angular code) will of course only ever run while your browser is open, in the backoffice, viewing this node.

What you want to do is to have this run automatically (and preferably in some sort of background task) to ensure that you do not really have to open up the backoffice for this to actually be automatically updated over time.

You need to create some sort of background job running on the server-side instead. This would have to be done in C# and I would recommend looking into Hangfire or Quartz frameworks to handle all the scheduling/making sure the job runs.

This job/task should do the external API calls in C# and transform the result into the same format as the format you are saving when you save data from the manual update. Then fetch the content nodes you need to update using the `ContentService` API and update the specific property values on those nodes. When this is done you need to make sure the changes are saved and the node is then republished with its updated data. All of this is done through the `ContentService`.